# Input names and output the first Initials of the surname and the first name

Tags: c, cs50

I enrolled in Harvard's cs50 via edx.org and I am stuck on this problem set two that  requires us to create a program that takes in peoples names and gives out the first initials of their first and surname names. The code is here:

```
string  initial (string a);  

int main (void)  
{  
    printf("Give me your name\n: ");  
    string name = GetString();  

    printf("Give me your second name\n:");  
    string sname = GetString();  

    char*c; char*b;  
    c = name;  
    b = sname;  

    printf("%s %s\n", initial(c),initial(b));  
}  

string initial (char*a)  
{  

        if ( *a >= 'A' && *a <= 'z')  
        {  
        return toupper(*a);  

        else  
        return ("please retype your name");  
        }  

}
```

This is the error message that I am getting from the compiler.

```
initials.c:27:16: error: incompatible integer to pointer conversion returning 'int' from a function with result type
      'string' (aka 'char *') [-Werror,-Wint-conversion]
        return toupper(*a);
               ^~~~~~~~~~~
initials.c:29:9: error: expected expression
        else
        ^
2 errors generated.
make: *** [initials] Error 1
```

What's wrong?

Comment: You're missing a  `}` and a `{` in your if/else statement

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/toupper/ `toupper` returns int which is definitely not a string.

Comment: @KamiKaze Note that this is a c++ resource and the language in the tag is not c++.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi it is a referencing a C library though `ctype.h`

Comment: *ctype.h* is not a c library. And in that website and even though I don't like it's format there is a c section for documenting every function that is originally from c, there are important differences that would make the documentation different between both languages.

Answer (score 0):

The `toupper()` function does not return a *string* and there is no such type in c, you have to convert each character so converting the first like this

```
a[0] = toupper(a[0]);
return a;
```

Note that what happens internally in any higher level language is exactly this, each character is converted individually.

Also note, that you are modifying the same object that you passed to the function, so the variable in your `main()` will be modified too.

And more importantly, using the `string` type defined as `char *` is very misleading, you are hiding many important things that a c programmer must be careful with

1. The variables of type `string` are pointers.
2. A string is really an array of characters terminated by a `'\0'` which is why i've written the `for` loop like I did.
3. By defining such type the programmer might infer that concatenating strings would be possible with the + operator, this would only cause what is known as undefined behavior.